# Image not coming the second time I click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i have applied a simple accordian-type list there the lists are all opened on loading . the problem is that when i click on a tab the first time, the image should changes from open to close icon, which is fine. but when i click that same tab again, the content slides down which is fine, but the image does not change from cklose to open.

the image classes are:

```
.close_accordianimage{ background:url(../img/close.png) left 9px no-repeat;}
.open_accordianimage{ background:url(../img/open.png) left 9px no-repeat;}
```

the script i used is:

```
//for opening and closing content on click of h3, and also adding of close image on click 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#odd-accordion h3").click(function() {
        $(this).next('div').toggle('300');
        $(this).addClass('close_accordianimage');
    });
});



</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#odd-accordion h3').addClass('open_accordianimage');
});
```

the html code sample is:

```
<div id="odd-accordion">
    <h3 class="filtertitle">Seater :</h3>

    <div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Seater</div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Sleeper</div>
    </div>
     <h3 class="filtertitle">A/C :</h3>

    <div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />A/C</div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Non-A/C</div>
    </div>
     <h3 class="filtertitle">Bus Brand :</h3>

    <div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Volvo/Mercedes</div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Non-Volvo/Mercedes</div>
    </div>
     <h3 class="filtertitle">Timing :</h3>

    <div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Early Morning
            <br /> <span class="timing">(5:00 AM - 9:00 AM)</span>

        </div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Morning/Afternoon
            <br /> <span class="timing">(9:00 AM - 5:00 PM)</span>

        </div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Evening
            <br /> <span class="timing">(5:00 PM - 9:00 PM)</span>

        </div>
        <div class="filterfield">
            <input type="checkbox" />Night
            <br /> <span class="timing">(9:00 PM - 5:00 AM) </span>

        </div>
    </div>
     <h3 class="filtertitle">Fare :</h3>

    <div>Jquery filer</div>
</div>
```

i just want the open and cose classes (having the respective images) to also toggle with content.please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$("#odd-accordion h3").click(function () {
    $(this).next('div').toggle('300');
    if ($(this).hasClass('close_accordianimage')) {
        $(this).addClass('open_accordianimage');
        $(this).removeClass('close_accordianimage');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('open_accordianimage');
        $(this).addClass('close_accordianimage');
    }
});
```

Try this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CM4m/)** and add the correct url for the images.

Comment: hi sergio, can you tell me why have you added console.log(this); in the answer, i mean what does it do

Comment: @gauravoberoi, console is a tool for debugging. It does nothing, just pass the value of `this` inside that click function. You can remove it. If you press `F12` in your browser it will open the console and you have many nice debugging tools. You can read a bit about it here.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you forgot to add `removeClass()` as well. Now you just keep stacking classes. Did you use Firebug or something like it to inspect the elements after you clicked it a few times, I bet it has a list of `close_accordianimage` duplicates on it.

To explain what happens, you start with the `open_accordianimage`, then the  `close_accordianimageduplicates`gets added, and it never gets removed. To do it properly I would remove the `open_accordianimage`, and add the  `close_accordianimageduplicates`, and visa versa.